# How come $D_4$ has 8 elements

Tags: group-theory

$D_4$ is the group of permutations on $A=(1,2,3,4)$

There exists $4!$ ways of reordering the terms of $A$ but $D_4$ has 8 members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of $D_4$ is wrong: it's the symmetries of the square.

Not all 24 ways of reordering the terms lead to transformations of the square. You can't transpose two adjacent corners, for example.